# Adding List of Customers to Sheet1 from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet where I want to add the list of customers on Column A of sheet1 from the same column in sheet2 - sheet13. Each sheet do not contain the same customer name but I want them to be listed on Column A of Sheet1. Is there a better way to have each of these names appear on column A of sheet1?

I am not very proficient with excel but I can learn quick.

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Office Excel MVP Ron de Bruin provides a number of samples to merge data from multiple worksheets into one summary worksheet:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793964.aspx

You can download his code, provided in a link in the article to get you going.

It will need some knowledge on VBA and you indicated that you are not proficient with Excel so you may need someone to help you implement this.